# Combining list x-y data with a list of errobars into one list (mathematica-style)

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, coding-style

Suppose I have a list of data I can ListPlot:

```
{ {x1,y1}, ... }
```

, and a list of y-errorbars:

```
{erry1, erry2, ... }
```

Is there a nice, high level way to make it into a list for ErrorListPlot:

```
{ {{x1,y1}, ErrorBar[erry1]}, ... }
```

It of course easy to do it through iteration in Table, however I keep reading about, how it is not the right way in Mathematica to use iterations (at least over lists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1 = {{x1, y1}, {x2, y2}, {x3, y3}};
data2 = {error1, error2, error3};
Transpose[{data1, ErrorBar /@ data2}]
Thread[{data1, ErrorBar /@ data2}]
```

> {{{x1, y1}, ErrorBar[error1]}, {{x2, y2}, 
>     ErrorBar[error2]}, {{x3, y3}, ErrorBar[error3]}}